# xamarin.forms set row height to 0 programmatically causes unwanted space

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid

I have a grid which contains some rows, and i want to make them invisible programmatically, and i do that by setting their heights to 0, it makes the height zero but there's still a little space where the row has been removed, i have attached 2 pictures, in picture 2, i have set the the height of IA1, IA2, IA3 rows to 0 and it causes a gap between VB1 and IB1, which i don't want to have, can anybody please help? Is there a way not to have this gap?

[image: this is the whole grid]
[image: this is the same grid after removing some rows]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the RowSpacing property on the grid to 0. You can do this in xaml.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Grid.RowSpacing/

Then, optionally, add the amount of padding you'd like on the content of each row, to preserve some spacing.

Comment: thank you so much, it worked, although i set margin for the content, not padding and it worked, thanks for giving me the idea